# Three.js - visually correct 3D render on top of static 2D image

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm trying to create a moveable 3D-view in three.js on top of a static 2D-rectangle image. Everything works fine, but I want the buildings at the upper edge to be "cut off" vertically so they appear to be placed visually correct on top of the static ground rectangle. Here are some pictures to illustrate the problem:

Desired appearance (only top of building is over the edge)

[image: screenshot 1]

Wrong appearance (bottom of building floating over the edge)

[image: screenshot 2]

So I want some kind of cut-off that slices the objects vertically at the top edge, however I'm unsure what the best method would be, I tried frustrum culling and putting the scene inside of a cube, but both of these didn't really work.

If that's not possible the next best solution might be to exclude objects that touch the edge from rendering completely, or what do you think?

Comment: Please add a [mcve], thank you.

Comment: Alright, I will build a fiddle with code right now, maybe that helps to illustrate it better. I thought pictures would be enough to show the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently what i want is called "Clipping Planes" and three.js supports those natively. Sorry for the somewhat confusingly worded question.